# How To Make AngularJS Work With HTML & jQuery Latest?

Tags: html, angularjs

Can i change this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/3/ to html & jquery?

I have this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXgmQX, but not work well. Anybody have idea?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you provide the information about the term `I have this, but not work well.`

Comment: Ok, wait i want to describe you

Comment: Here is my code to try code in that fiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXgmQX

Comment: your codepen just has whatever you copied from your local machine, it is referring to `js/angular.js` and `js/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js` which don't exist on codepen.  You might start off with pointing these two files to their appropriate CDN

Comment: Claies, please look again i have edited on codepen

Comment: this code is using a deprecated syntax which will not work with angular 1.3 or higher.  See https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/guide/migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide `ng-app` in your html

Add this

```
ng-app="app"
```

and put your js below div before the body close tag (`</body>`) **[`Like this`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZrZwq?editors=101)**

Comment: it won't work on codepen because angular file you refer is on locahost. provide cdn link and it'll fly in the codepen.

Comment: You just messed controller with other http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZrZwq?editors=101